# I am an 100 letter word, who am I?

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

I have been watching you.

From the moment you were first conscious, I have been watching;

Until the last time you lose consciousness, I will be watching.

I am always by your side, witnessing you.

Everything you remember,

every heartbreak, every happy moment,

every pride, every regret,

every option you choose, every action you take,

every thought you form,

I know ***ALL*** about you.

I am always there, you can't get rid of me;

I am not omnipresent, I do not follow you,

yet everywhence you go, I am there.

You can never see me directly, yet everywhere you look,

I am at the center of everything.

I have many names, 1, 6645615 and 2130706433...

> MmgzMzM5MHcycDM2MnQwdzMyMzMzODB3M2QzMzM5MTgwdzNkMzMzOTB3MnAzNjJ0MHczMTJ0

Who am I?

Comment: Note the string 100 in the title doesn't mean one hundred.

Comment: The word is extremely common.

Comment: rot13(Gung ynfg ahzore genafyngvat gb bar uhaqerq gjragl frira qbg mreb qbg mreb qbg bar) is not a coincidence, is it?

Comment: Yes, you spotted it. It was meant to be localhost.

Comment: The verb "watch" in the question doesn't necessarily mean observing optically, but something more general.

Comment: Does the number 2130706433 continue (as ascertained by the dots) or do they denote additional separate numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> `SELF`. The "witness" and "see directly" clues could start an argument.

Cipher:

> Appears to say `YOU ARE NOT YOU. YOU ARE ME` but I can't work out the exact method. Looks like Caesar was applied first, then encoded in hex, then another substitution on the hex before the base64?

Comment: The message is first encoded using Base-36 (replace each byte with a two digit Base-36 string), then encoded again in Base-64. It is the equivalence operator in ArnoldC, and the second number translated to bytes and decoded using ASCII is 'ego'.

Comment: What's the significance of the two long numbers at the end of the riddle? (1 I get...)

Comment: the 2nd was explained in a comment right before yours.  the third is hinted at by a comment on another answer. rot13(vg'f na ba-gurzr vc nqqerff jevggra nf n fvatyr qrpvzny)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Your pupil/Eyes? (I apologize for double-guessing)

Since:

From the moment you were first conscious, I have been watching;

Until the last time you lose consciousness, I will be watching.

> Because Your eyes "watch" whenever, as in looking (I'm guessing closing your eyes still counts as them watching your eyelid)

Everything you remember,

every heartbreak, every happy moment,

every pride, every regret,

every option you choose, every action you take,

every thought you form,

I know ALL about you.

> Because your eyes obviously see everything you are doing, embarrassing or not (lol)

I am always there, you can't get rid of me;

> It WOULD after all be weird

I am not omnipresent, I do not follow you,

yet everywhence you go, I am there.

> Should your eyes count as following you?

You can never see me directly,

> You can't see your eyes "directly" (looking into a mirror doesn't count!)

yet everywhere you look,

I am at the center of everything.

> Your pupils are after all at the center of your eyes

If this isn't the right answer,(I would expect that- I didn't use all the clues) then do your worst lol (deletion)

Edit: The title says 100, which COULD BE (kindergarten logic) 1(eye)(eye)
like 1️️ you know lol

Another edit: 100 in binary translates to 4, which should mean that the final answer has four letters

Comment: Close, but not quite. The answer is indeed four letters, but it is not "eyes", but something related to it.

Comment: Would it be related to your "back"? <--as in another guess

Comment: Since I was exploring the term "localhost" online, it gave me the term "loopback". Plus, as I reasoned, you cannot see your back...

Comment: The number 100 in binary can translate to 4, so the title would be saying "I am a 4 letter word"

Comment: Sorry, but you missed again, your guess is close, though.